# I just want to select the button with the text "Continue" within a website with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I search for the button by the common method it returns 2 results

```
cy.get('[data-testid="cc-button__element"] > [data-testid="cc-button__text"]')
```

[image: screenshot-1]

However, when I do the search with cypress's own tool, it does locate it quickly and returns 1 result.

```
cy.get('.block > [data-testid="cc-button"] > [data-testid="cc-button__element"]')
```

[image: screenshot-2]

I know that this is valid, however, I want to do it by the traditional method so that later if there are changes it does not affect my button search methods.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: those are 2 very different queries

Comment: Add the HTML of the button to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text Continue occurs just once in your webpage you can use `contains` to find it and click it.

```js
cy.contains('Continue').click()
```